# Sending Attachment to HttpRequest POST C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send an attachment using HttpRequest, but the server give me a 500 Internal Server Error.

If i make the same call from SOAP UI, it will success with this result.

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 13:47:00 GMT Server: Apache Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains;
> preload Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: multipart/related;
> boundary="MIMEBoundary_ccc0c7786f280ccc7fb981fb343b4463e574457582881961";
> type="application/xop+xml";
> start="0.dcc0c7786f280ccc7fb981fb343b4463e574457582881961@apache.org";
> start-info="text/xml"
>
> --MIMEBoundary_ccc0c7786f280ccc7fb981fb343b4463e574457582881961 Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary Content-ID:
> 0.dcc0c7786f280ccc7fb981fb343b4463e574457582881961@apache.org
>
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
> ...</soapenv:Envelope>
> --MIMEBoundary_ccc0c7786f280ccc7fb981fb343b4463e574457582881961--

So i'm mistaking the link between soap request and attachment.

What could be the error inside the code?

The code is called by a c# Web Api and is calling a SOAP POST resource.

```
public static string Start()
{
    var _url = "...";
    var _action = "...";
    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = SoapEnvelope();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);
    // begin async call to web request.
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
    // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
    // do something usefull here like update your UI.
    asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    // get the response from the completed web request.
    string soapResult;
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.Write(soapResult);
    }
    return "";
}

private static XmlDocument SoapEnvelope()
{
    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeDocument = new XmlDocument();
    soapEnvelopeDocument.LoadXml(
    @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
        .... 
    </soapenv:Envelope>");
    return soapEnvelopeDocument;
}

public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    return webRequest;
}

private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var data = GetFromData("dummy.pdf", @"C:\dummy.pdf", webRequest);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
    }
}

public static byte[] GetFromData(string fileName, string filePath, HttpWebRequest request)
{
    var attachment = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    string boundaryString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    MemoryStream postDataStream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter postDataWriter = new StreamWriter(postDataStream);
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString;
    postDataWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundaryString + "\r\n");
    postDataWriter.Flush();
    postDataWriter.Write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n", "file", fileName, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));
    postDataWriter.Flush();
    postDataStream.Write(attachment, 0, attachment.Length);
    postDataWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundaryString + "--\r\n");
    postDataWriter.Flush();
    return postDataStream.ToArray();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: See the msdn example for what a mime looks like.  A mime in a body of a message is one a new line that starts with two dashes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: dont' understand your comment...

Comment: The 500 error indicates an exception occurred in sever when processing your request. Since you have attachments there may be something wrong with the attachment or you do not have privilege do access resources in the server.   Since you said "I'm trying to send an attachment" I gave a ling to show what a properly formed mime attachment looks like.